# Minimum set that must have a square product subset

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Following on from [Victor's interesting numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2577171/206402), I was trying to find how big a set of "interesting" 29-smooth numbers (those which can be represented as the product of numbers under $30$) needs to be so that there must be some selection of numbers that has a square product.

I am allowing the selection to be only one number (so the individual numbers in the set can be assumed not to be square) or more numbers up to the full set, but not of course zero numbers.

Given that we are working within a scope of ten prime factors, and largely concerned with the parity of the exponents of those factors, I was thinking of algorithms to combine the members of the set in pairs and gradually reduce to subsets with even product exponents, which with "dumb" implementation of blindly pairing in fixed order would not improve on a set size of about $2^{10}$ but with slightly more intelligence could bring this down to a little over $2^5$ by working on pairs of primes.

Is there a better approach, while I think about further details of this algorithmic method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need $11$ numbers.  The same pigeonhole principle approach as in the linked question works.  There are $10$ primes less than $30$, so there are $2^{10}=1024$ pigeonholes which are the parity of each of the $10$ primes.  If you have more than $1024$ subsets, two of them have the same parity pattern.  The union of those two subsets, deleting common members, will have a square product.  To show we need $11$, you can just take the set of ten primes less than $30$.  No subset except the empty set has a square product.

Comment: Easy as that, powersets. Thanks.